# Using Javascript to run a function, but keep the URL intact

Tags: javascript, sharepoint

I'm using this [console log code](https://support.shortpoint.com/support/solutions/articles/1000271169-cannot-see-links-exit-classic-experience-or-return-to-classic-sharepoint-) Here's the code below:

```
<a href="javascript:(function(){document.cookie = `splnu=0;domain=${window.location.hostname};`; location.href = `${_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl}/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx`;})();">Classic</a>
<a href="javascript:(function(){document.cookie = `splnu=1;domain=${window.location.hostname};`; location.href = `${_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl}/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx`;})();">Modern</a>
```

I found out how to switch a SharePoint between Classic and Modern view and converted it to JavaScript. I'm not too familiar with the last part of the code where it redirects the URL to the Site Contents of a SharePoint page.

`location.href =` ${_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl}/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx`

I'm trying to figure out how to keep that from happening and not refresh the URL, so that the URL stays intact.

Thank you for reviewing in advance.

Comment: Can you remove the `location.href...` expression?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the void keyword. The void keyword indicates that the function does not return a value, which prevents the browser from navigating away from the current page.

```
<a href="javascript:void(function(){document.cookie='splnu=0;domain='+window.location.hostname;location.href=_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl+'/_layouts/15/viewlsts.aspx';}())">Classic</a>
```

Modern